# Watch pattern to combine multiple variables into one watch

Tags: angularjs, watch

sometimes when I implement watch pattern in my directives in angular, I need to evaluate multiple values at once but want the watch pattern to trigger only once. Lately I found the watchGroup that I was hoping it would do exactly the mentioned behavior above but unfortunately it doesn't so I came up with this idea of hashing my values to in a watch using a function as a first parameter. So I was wondering is this a good idea? Is there pitfall in this pattern?

Assuming that foo and bar are values between 0-99.

```
$scope.$watch(function(){ return foo*100+bar}, function(){//This only triggers once!});
```

Thanks for the inputs.

Mark

Comment: If variables are watched together, maybe they are somehow related? If so, maybe it's a good idea to group them into single object? `{ foo: 10, bar: 20}` and then watch this single variable. Generally `$watchGroup` should do the job. Maybe you were using it in a wrong way?

Comment: Hey scareddragon, my watchGroup might be firing multiple time for some unrelated reason. I will review this later. It seems logical though that the digest cycle will fire two times when both my foo and bar updates but I would like to avoid atleast my watch to trigger twice.

Answer (score 0):

have your tried $watchCollection(obj, listener)? this API can help you watch an array of values.

check out [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)